# Cloud Firestore Security Rules matching collections?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a firestore database called `myDb`. This database has documents named  from a 10 character random string. Each of those documents then have a sub-collection named from a 10 character random string. Then each of those sub-collections have a sub-document called `fields`. Ex:

```
myDb/DFRGHJKEWD/KHBJHVHGSD/fields
```

Currently my security rules are as follows:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to `allow update` on any `fields` sub-document. How would I do this?

Also, is there a way to set up rules for specific user-agents? Like if a request is coming from a specific application?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for security rules? Is there something in particular that you're stuck on?  It seems to me you haven't yet made an attempt at writing a rule that meets your needs.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Comment: "Also, is there a way to set up rules for specific user-agents? Like if a request is coming from a specific application?" Nope, that's not possible.

Comment: @DougStevenson the documentation isn't clear on how to wildcard collections.

Comment: You should be able to wildcard collections in the same way you wildcard documents. I don't believe rules make any distinction between the two for the purpose of satisfying a match.  If this isn't working the way you expect, please ask a question showing the exact rules that you think should match but don't.

Comment: @DougStevenson `match /{collection}/fields` is not working though...

Comment: You can't put document fields in a match.  It can only contain collection names an document IDs.